# How to implement onClickListener for a specific element inside RecyclerView itemView in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I want to implement an onClickListener for the followButton inside an item in a RecylerView. I haven't managed to find any tutorial/question which uses the way I followed and am completely clueless about the required approach in Kotlin.
Here is the code for the adapter class where I have just managed to successfully implement an onItemClickListener for the itemView.

```
class adapterClass(private val exampleList : List<objectClass>, private val listener : onItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterClass.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false)
        return  ViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
       val currentItem = exampleList[position]

        val url: String = currentItem.imageResourceLink
        val circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(holder.itemView.context)
        circularProgressDrawable.strokeWidth = 10f
        circularProgressDrawable.centerRadius = 100f
        circularProgressDrawable.start()
        GlideApp.with(holder.itemView.context).load(url).circleCrop().placeholder(circularProgressDrawable).error(R.drawable.error).fallback(R.drawable.fallback).transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).into(holder.imageView)
        holder.textView1.text = currentItem.text1
        holder.textView2.text = currentItem.text2
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = exampleList.size



    inner class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener{

        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
        val followButton: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.followButton)

        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)

        }


        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            val position : Int = adapterPosition
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position)
            }

        }

    }

    interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position:Int)
    }

}
```

If possible, I would like the same way to be followed as is currently used(onClickListener in ViewHolder), to ensure reusability of this adapter throughout the app.
Thanks.

Comment: Setting it on the whole itemView will set whole the view as clickable, since you just want to set it on follow button, just do this `followButton.setOnClickListener { listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition) }`

Comment: Also, how would I do it for multiple items if needed?

Comment: Add More functions to your interface according to whatever you need like `fun onFollowButtonClick()` or `fun onTextViewClick()` or you could send a type in a single function itself like `fun onItemClick(position:Int, typeOfClick:Int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting OnClickListener for itemView which makes the view clickable.. If you want to set OnClickListener for only followButton just set OnClickListner only for followButton.

```
init {

        followButton .setOnClickListener(this)

    }
```